# html input values in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I can't seem to figure out this problem that I have:

```
<script>
    function getValues(){
        var value1 = document.getElementById("value1");
        var value2 = document.getElementById("value2");
        var value3 = document.getElementById("value3");
        alert(value1 +" "+ value2 +" "+ value3);
    }
</script>

<p>value1</p>   
<input type="text" id='value1' />
<p>value2</p>
<input type="text" id='value2' />
<p>value3</p>
<input type="text" id='value3' />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="getValues()" />
```

I try to get the values the user filled in and then alert them back to them but instead of showing the values they filled in, it says:

> `[object HTMLInputElement] [object HTMLInputElement] [object HTMLInputElement]`

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var value1 = document.getElementById("value1");`

Gets the DOM Element associated with the `value1` Id. In order to get the value of the element you need to do:

`var value1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;`.

Comment: the explanation of why the .value has to be added helped me understand it better. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Try it like this

```
function getValues(){

        var value1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
        var value2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
        var value3 = document.getElementById("value3").value;
        alert(value1 +" "+ value2 +" "+ value3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("value1")`returns a dom element.

To assign it, get the value by using it like this:

```
document.getElementById("value1").value
```